# Is informated a word?

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english, lexicon

On Season 1 Ep 5 in the TV Show Good Omens, a US military soldier guarding a US base says:

> I was not **informated** on any surprise inspection sir.

Clip of video here: https://streamable.com/l6acv6

Then another replied “Well, if you had it wouldn’t be a surprise, now would it?”

To my knowledge, it is not a subtitle mistake as the voice matches the subtitles exactly. The time stamp is at @40:24 - 40:26 (mm:ss), if anyone can watch the full episode.

I had never heard anyone say it before and it is not found in any dictionary. Is this some form of American military lingo?

Comment: It could just be a mis-speak on the part of the actor, which got incorporated into the subtitles.

Comment: Perhaps, but a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/goodomens/comments/c5zluo/i_was_not_informated_says_the_air_base_guard/) suggests it could be some form of military talk. However, I don’t have any form of evidence from any ‘official authority’ regarding the latter.

Comment: @fev great answer! Who knew a linguist such as Chomsky used “to be informated” in the same was as the way the verb phrase “to be informed” is used... however I wonder why a linguist such as Chomsky would use a word which is not in the official lexicon.

Comment: @Jay Yes, that's what I thought. If he uses it, it most probably exists and is correct. There is just not enough documentation on line about it. With this connotation, it may be actually older than with Shoshana Zuboff's connotation.

Comment: To be *informated* sounds like the recipient has been stuffed with (dis)information as opposed to being genuinely informed. Kind of like being *medicated* as opposed to being treated or cured.

Answer (score 9):

Good Omens is a comic novel, and in this case the author's intention may not have been to have the soldier use real military terminology, but to satirize the way soldiers, and specifically American soldiers, are perceived to use jargon, acronyms and neologisms in their interaction with other soldiers or civilians.

Comment: This is absolutely what's going on. The context is everything,

Comment: And it's in the original book. You can see many more such examples there.

Answer (score 3):

It is most probably used in intentional, overly formal language. It probably means ***informed***, and I keep saying "probably", because there is little information about the term out there. What is certain is that, ***to informate*** is a recent new term (so recent that ***informated*** and ***informating*** are underlined with red by the [spell checkers](https://www.spellcheck.net/misspelled-words/informated)):

> ***Informating*** is a term coined by Shoshana Zuboff in her book In the Age of the Smart Machine (***1988***).[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informating) It is the process that
> ***translates descriptions and measurements of activities, events and
> objects into information***. By doing so, these activities become visible
> to the organization.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informating))

Now Shoshana Zuboff is a Harvard professor, so she didn't just invent the term without a specific and well-documented need.

It's pretty obvious that you do not ***informate*** a person in that sense. In the clip, it is a soldier speaking and it is possible that the director wanted to use an overly formal language.

I couldn't find information on how this term was used to give a more official version of ***inform***, but I did find it in official documents like this one ([Bootcampmilitary](https://bootcampmilitaryfitnessinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/0002d-green-to-gold-application-checklist.pdf)) saying:

> You will be ***informated*** of your final status no later than 30 June.

Noam Chomsky seems to know this term, too. He says:

> It seems the Front was ***informated*** by Turkish intelligence. ([Source](https://www.albawaba.com/loop/noam-chomsky-claims-turkish-intelligence-sold-out-us-trained-rebels-al-qaeda-770830))

So there you go, the military do use it, but whether wrongly or not is still to be determined.

It is possible that the verb "to informate" was associated with "being informed using technology".

**ADDITION**: I got intrigued by the term, so I decided to dig a bit deeper. In this thesis on the site [webcorp.org.uk](http://webcorp.org.uk) this term is included in a list of results of *separating blends*. The article is called

> A FORMAL INVESTIGATION OF THE
> BLENDING PROCESS IN ENGLISH AND
> ITS RELATIONSHIP TO ASSOCIATED
> WORD FORMATION PROCESSES

and what it is interesting is that it shows how the verb was formed:

> informated - informed + educated (see p. 352)

I also found an interesting [blog](https://arnoldzwicky.org/2010/01/23/informate/) that calls it a ***back-formed word***. I am not saying this is an authoritative claim, but it does shed some light on how native English speakers use it:

[image]

The blog says

> The verb is sometimes glossed as ‘dispense information’, but that scarcely conveys its intended import in context, where it’s frequently contrasted with *automate*.

and then goes on giving an example which speaks of *the terminological innovation as a **“semantic change”.*** So it is possible that this term may have gone through such a process.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection is a related concept here that could help tie together a lot of these disparate examples